# Circular dependency with static methods

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies, circular-dependency

I know circular dependency is nothing good for objects, but I wonder if in my example there is any reason to worry. Well angular at least claims that yes - logging warning all the time.

```
export class A {
  static methodA1(dialog: MdDialog) { B.methodB1(dialog); }
}

export class B {
  static methodB1(dialog: MdDialog) { } 
  static methodB2(dialog: MdDialog) { A.methodA1(dialog); } 
}
```

Comment: Would you like to give us a clue which warning? When I throw the code you posted at typescript it is perfectly happy with it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Circular dependency detected:

A-> B -> A.  I pass some parameters with it. Well maybe that's the problem. 1 minute and it will be edited.

Comment: So that would be a warning from angular generated by how your components interact. It isn't a warning triggered by the code you posted. Please edit your question to include a minimal complete and verifiable example that will reproduce the warning.